Shortcuts and metadata - How to copy and paste metadata from one photo/video to another using shortcuts app?
Can’t find answer to this anywhere!
Using the shortcuts app, is there a way to automate the process of taking metadata (or at least location, date, time) from a photo/video and pasting it into another photo/video?
This shortcut gets half way there..
https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/4a1e6dc3c73645618e72b7bf67127050
Any help appreciated thanks!
iOS 17.5.1, iPhone SE 2020
